# Curves not invariant by non-trivial projective automorphisms

Tags: algebraic-curves, projective-varieties, automorphisms

Let $g\ge 0$, $d\ge 1$ be integers. We consider the Moduli space $H_{g,d}$ parametrising smooth irreducible closed curves $C\subset \mathbb{P}^3$ of degree $d$ and genus $g$. Let us denote by $U_{g,d}$ the subset consisting of curves $C$ such that $\{f\in \mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{P}^3)\mid f(C)=C\}$ is trivial.

**For which $g,d$ is $U_{g,d}$ a dense open subset of $H_{g,d}$ ?**

I have the impression that $U_{g,d}$ is always open in $H_{g,d}$. I would for this consider $X=\{(f,C)\mid f\in \mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{P}^3, C\in H_{g,d}\mid f(C)=C\}$, and look at the projection to $H_{g,d}$. The fibres with at least two elements should be closed I guess (unless the ones with one element in the fibre come with multiplicity...).

For $g=0$ and $d\in \{1,2,3\}$, then $U_{g,d}$ is simply empty, as all automorphisms of lines, conics and twisted cubics extend to $\mathbb{P}^3$. Similarly, $U_{1,3}$ is also empty as plane cubics always have some automorphisms extending (finitely many). Is  $U_{g,d}$ a dense open subset of $H_{g,d}$ for the others $(g,d)$?

**Edit:** As pointed by Robert Bryant, all curves contained in a plane gives $U_{g,d}=\varnothing$. One should then forget the cases where $g=\frac{(d-1)(d-2)}{2}$, so $(0,1),(0,2),(1,3),(3,4), (6,5), (10,6),\ldots$

Comment: Well, you'll also have $U_{3,4}$ is empty because Castelnuovo's bound implies that an irreducible space curve of degree $4$ and genus $3$ must lie in a $\mathbb{P}^2\subset\mathbb{P}^3$ (and be smooth), so there will always be nontrivial automorphisms of $\mathbb{P}^3$ that fix the $\mathbb{P}^2$ pointwise.  I think you need to at least restrict to non-degenerate curves.

Comment: $U_{1,4}$ also is empty: quartic elliptic curves have nontrivial automorphisms.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. @abx where is the automorphism coming from?

Comment: I think that a "rigorous" argument  for the openness could proceed as follows (although it's a bit overkill): Let $X$ be the quotient stack $\mathcal{X}:=[H_{g,d}/ \mathrm{PGL}_4]$. To show that $U_{g,d}$ is open it suffices to show that it is the pull-back of an open $U$ in $\mathcal{X}$. By (include reference to stacks project), the substack $U$ of $\mathcal{X}$ of points with trivial inertia group is open in $\mathcal{X}$. (Short argument: It is the locus over which the inertia stack is an isomorphism.) Note that $U_{g,d}$ is the pull-back of $U$.

Comment: I think what @abx is alluding to is that a space curve of genus 1 and degree 4 is the intersection of two quadrics that can be simultaneously diagonalized, i.e., $${X_0}^2+{X_1}^2+{X_2}^2+{X_3}^2 =a_0 {X_0}^2+a_1{X_1}^2+a_2{X_2}^2+a_3{X_3}^2=0,$$ and the maps $(X_i)\mapsto(\epsilon_iX_i)$ with $\epsilon_i = \pm1$ (and not all equal) are then nontrivial automorphisms of the curve, since they fix the quadrics.

Comment: @Robert Bryant: Yes, that's probably the easiest way to see it. A fancier way is to say that the embedding is given by a line bundle $L$ of degree 4 on the elliptic curve $E$, and that the subgroup of points of order 2 of $E$ acts equivariantly on $\mathbb{P}^3=\mathbb{P}(H^0(E,L)^*)$.

Comment: These are nice automorphisms. Is it possible to see that these are the only ones? For genus $0$, it seems to me that $U_{g,d}$ is dense and open as soon as $d\ge 5$ (take the Veronese embedding in $\mathbb{P}^4$, and project from a general point.) For any genus, I think that as soon as $d$ is large it should be OK. The small values would then give nice symmetric properties.